# Lax HTML parsing in C++?

Tags: c++, html-parsing

I'm looking for a solution for parsing potentially malformed HTML in C++, similar to what [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) does in Python.

Normally, just using an XML parser would work, but the specific HTML in this case isn't valid XML/XHTML and can't be properly parsed.

Do libraries/tools for this exist?

Comment: Changed the title slightly -- I would expect most C++ users to not be familiar with Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: @Billy And I would expect someone with 21k rep to close as duplicate not to change its title :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to transform HTML into valid XML and then use any C++ XML parser availiable

Comment: And as it's open source C code, you could (depending on licensing of course) actually link the core of HTMLTidy into your C++ binary.

Comment: @Billy Well, that's the solution you are **forced** to come up with because surprisingly there are no such parsers in C++. At least I couldn't find any some time ago. That's especially surprising when you know that most (all?) major web browsers' engines are written in C++. The problem is these parsers are not available as standalone components.

Comment: I think this project has been superseded by this project: [HTML Tidy for HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation [LibXml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) is capable of parsing HTML4.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-3.html) and recommend it for C++. It has both DOM and SAX model.

Comment: Xerces will not handle non-standards-conformant documents. Nor can it parse HTML.